# Windows event log - Security - Audit failure

Tags: audit, account-security

Every one hour or so I have this event in my `Event viewer -> Windows logs -> Security` log.

I understand the `consent.exe` is Windows' UAC control, what i wan't to know is why and what is trying to log into my administrator account every 30 min / every 1h.

The detail of the log is (I have a bunch of these btw.):

```
An account failed to log on.

Subject:
    Security ID:        SYSTEM
    Account Name:       DESKTOP-8P22P26$
    Account Domain:     WORKGROUP
    Logon ID:       0x3E7

Logon Type:         2

Account For Which Logon Failed:
    Security ID:        NULL SID
    Account Name:       Admin
    Account Domain:     DESKTOP-8P22P26

Failure Information:
    Failure Reason:     Unknown user name or bad password.
    Status:         0xC000006D
    Sub Status:     0xC000006A

Process Information:
    Caller Process ID:  0x2260
    Caller Process Name:    C:\Windows\System32\consent.exe

Network Information:
    Workstation Name:   DESKTOP-8P22P26
    Source Network Address: ::1
    Source Port:        0

Detailed Authentication Information:
    Logon Process:      CredPro
    Authentication Package: Negotiate
    Transited Services: -
    Package Name (NTLM only):   -
    Key Length:     0
```

Comment: The substatus 0xC000006A means that whatever is failing has the correct username but incorrect password. Which is weird because the account for which logon failed has a null sid which usually means bad username...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Logon Type:         2

2 means it is Interactive (logon at keyboard and screen of system)

> Security ID:        NULL SID

Subject is usually Null or one of the Service principals, though not that useful.

> Logon Process:      CredPro

CredPro indicates a logon initiated by User Account Control

---

With these, you can determine that someone is in fact trying to log on. At regular intervals, could be a script (maybe, at that lenght they are trying to make it seem like it's another admin or something, compared to trying to log on every 30 minutes).

See [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/multiple-login-attempts-and-audit-failures-in/7162945e-818b-4178-bcc4-c47101e74b5a) from MSFT of what looks like a similar issue.

---

Also if you are watching Event Viewer, I'd also suggest centralizing the Event Logs maybe to another dashboard (useful if the account becomes compromised). See these types of modules [here](https://nxlog.co/documentation/nxlog-user-guide-full#windows-eventlog) (I'm involved in the project) and also others that can collect EventLog events into another format like JSON.